# Convert MultiIndex to single date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, multi-index

I have a dataframe whereby the index is a multiindex as follows;

```
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
2020 6
     7
     8
     9
     10
     11
     12
```

As I need daily values I'm looking to convert it to a columns which would be as follows;

```
Date
2020/01/01
2020/02/01
2020/03/01
2020/04/01
2020/05/01

etc
```

so that I can then use;

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('D').ffill()
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in index are only `year` and `month` levels use list comprehension with change format for joined strings:

```
#python 3
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{a}-{b}-01' for a, b in df.index])

#python 2
df.index = pd.to_datetime(['{}-{}-01'.format(a, b) for a, b in df.index])
```

If ther are also days:

```
#python 3
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{a}-{b}-{c}' for a, b, c in df.index])

#python 2
df.index = pd.to_datetime(['{}-{}-{}'.format(a, b, c) for a, b, c in df.index])
```

And then:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').ffill()
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error in relation to the 01'  
Any ideas?

Comment: @spcol - What is your python version? If change `01` to `1` it working?

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to be working either. Using version 2.7.16.

Comment: df.index = pd.to_datetime(['{}-{}-{}'.format(y,m,d) for y,m,d in df.index])  ..something like this?? just can't seem to crack it

Comment: @spcol - in index are also days? not only years and months?

Comment: only months and years, I shouldn't have been using d in the above. your edit works perfectly! thanks!